# How to properly use ref with indiana drag scroll to set initial scroll position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

I've been trying to implement the initial scroll from https://codesandbox.io/s/react-indiana-drag-scroll-initial-scroll-getelement-99o6q?file=/index.js:317-382

But haven't had much luck getting the ref to work it seems, or perhaps it is something with the render cycle.

Here is my code to reference with the codesandbox:

```
   export default function ProjectCarousel() {
  const container = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    container.current.getElement().scrollTo(0, 240);
  }, []);

  return (
    <ScrollContainer className="scroll-container" ref={container}>
      {ProjectData.map(({ id, ...otherProps }) => (
        <ProjectImage key={id} {...otherProps} />
      ))}
    </ScrollContainer>
  );
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use property `innerRef` instead on `ref`